# order_by is not working with Unicode in django with request.GET data

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to filter my results in ascending order based on my field. But orderby is not working when I use below code. I am receiving unicode and converting it to string. Please help me.

```
def users(request):
    user_list = User.objects.filter(user_type='Customer')

    #sort by
    if request.GET.get('sortby'):
      user_list.order_by(str(request.GET.get('sortby')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a simple case that you aren't "saving" the ordering?

```
user_list = user_list.order_by(str(request.GET.get('sortby')))
```

Comment: oh! ok forgot to save. Thank you.